# Java - Recursion just stops and i don't understand why

Tags: java, recursion

So as stated in the title i'm confronted with the issue that my program wont iterate through all possible directories of my computer.

With this code i'm trying to find the root folder without a parent and then from there on go through all folders and their children folders and so on.

After running it goes through the first directory (for me it's C:) and finds all visible children folders.
Afterwards it goes into the first Folder and exits it again, due to it not containing any further directories.
The second directory it approaches **only exists within** the compiler and doesn't show up in my explorer even though it is not supposed to be hidden.

My Compiler stops here and doesn't throw an error message.

**Code:**

```
public class Main {

public static File getRootFile(File file){
        boolean hasParent = true;
        while (hasParent){
            File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
            file = parentFile;
            hasParent = file.getParentFile() != null;
        }
        return file;
}
//Recursion with starting file parameter
public static void rekursion(File pathFile) {
    String path = pathFile.toString();
    File[] directories_with_hiddenFiles = new File(path).listFiles(File::isDirectory);
    int notNull = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i< directories_with_hiddenFiles.length;i++){
        if (!directories_with_hiddenFiles[i].isHidden()){
            notNull++;
        }
    }
    File[] directories = new File[notNull];
    for (int i=0, j=0;i<directories_with_hiddenFiles.length;i++){
        if(!directories_with_hiddenFiles[i].isHidden()){
            directories[j]=directories_with_hiddenFiles[i];
            j++;

        }
    }

    //Calls up recursion for each file
    try {
        for (File a : directories) {
            rekursion(a);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Starting Point (Root)
    File pathOfThisFile = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    File rootFile = getRootFile(pathOfThisFile);
    rekursion(rootFile);
}
}
```

Comment: You should get into the habit of debugging your code, add some breakpoints and understand what is going on in each loop, you will eventually get to the root of the problem

Comment: 1) It's highly suspicious that you need to handle a `NullPointerException`. It's better to check for `null`. 2) If an NPE occurrs you just silence it... did you try to check whether this is happening? Maybe your code is exploding with NPEs whihc you are currently completely ignoring and then it ends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid your complicated code by passing both conditions you want to check into initial query:

```
File[] directories = new File(path).listFiles(f -> f.isDirectory() && !f.isHidden()); // loads all not hidden subdirectories, which is what you are trying to do
if (directories != null) { // listFiles can return null, so check it before iterating
    for (File a : directories) {
              rekursion(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I couldn't find a way initially to add Filter to my listFiles method. The issue here was that some folders were non accessible/readable junction points. Checking for wether directories is null or not fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception when your recursive function get a directory where the user that you are using to run dosen't have permission to read,
and

```
File[] directories_with_hiddenFiles = new File(path).listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

will return null.

you can use File.canRead() to check that, honestly your code has much more than one problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've patched it up and it works all fine now.

Comment: If it solve your problem please mark it as useful/correct  response